# Concrete import requirements for dogs and cats to the US

Tags: usa, pets

I'm moving to the US this year (from a rabies free country) and I have cats and dogs. I have been in touch with the agricultural authority in the US and I have read the CDC website as well as the state specific website.

But nowhere could I find a specific to do list with links to the necessary forms to fill in. I want to avoid quarantine. I've exchanged several emails with a person in charge in the US and it's still not clear what exactly I have to do.

> Does anyone here know exactly what I have to do and where I can
>   download the forms that the vets in the country of origin need to fill
>   in?

I think it's bizarre that there is no government website with a step by step guide and the necessary (empty) forms for download.

Comment: Remember that you need to consider state, as well as federal, requirements. For example, your dogs may need to be vaccinated against rabies to meet state requirements.

Comment: http://www.cdc.gov/importation/pdf/dogimportation_us-canada.pdf summarizes the rules and should cover you for entering any state except Hawaii. You may need to have your rabies certificates translated into English.

Answer (score 2):

The US Department of Agriculture Animal and Plant Health Inspection Services offers the following [guidelines](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/aphis/ourfocus/importexport/animal-import-and-export/travel-with-a-pet/ct_animal_imports_pets):

> **CATS AND DOGS**
>
> The Centers for Disease Control and Prevention (CDC) has regulations
>   on the importation of dogs and cats into the United States. To protect
>   public health within the United States, importers who bring dogs to
>   the United States must make sure that their dogs are adequately
>   vaccinated against rabies before arrival. There are three (3) federal
>   Agencies that have regulations that pertain to the import of dogs. 
>   They are:  USDA Veterinary Services (VS), USDA  Animal Care  (AC) and
>   the Centers for Disease Control (CDC). In general, all dogs must be
>   vaccinated against rabies after three months old and cannot be
>   imported until at least 30  days after vaccination.  The CDC allows 
>   unvaccinated dogs to be imported without proof of a rabies vaccination
>   if they have lived in a country that is considered rabies free for a
>   minimum of six months or since birth. The Animal Care has rabies
>   regulations for dogs imported into the Continental United States or
>   Hawaii for the purpose of resale, adoption or rehoming.  Consult the
>   Animal Care for definitive information on their requirements. Access
>   those requirements Here: Importers may need to obtain a confinement
>   agreement from the CDC, for puppies prior to U.S arrival.  Entry may
>   be refused if dogs/puppies arrive without this agreement or
>   vaccination. We strongly suggest that you visit the CDC web site at:
>   http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/dogs.html  or call them at
>   1-800-232-4636, for more information on their regulations.
>
> The CDC regulations pertaining to cats can be found by following this
>   link: http://www.cdc.gov/animalimportation/cats.html
>
> The U.S. Department of Agriculture has certain restrictions on the
>   importation of dogs. Collies, shepherds, and other dogs that are
>   imported from any part of the world except Canada, Mexico, and regions
>   of Central America and the West Indies and that are to be used in the
>   handling of livestock must be inspected and quarantined at the port of
>   entry for a sufficient time to determine their freedom from tapeworm.
>
> APHIS VS requirements for all dogs imported or returning from
>   countries affected with screwworm:
>
> Pet and other types of dogs (commercial, breeding, etc.) that are
>   returning, and/or are presented for US entry, from countries or
>   regions where screwworm is known to exist, may enter the US if they
>   meet the following requirements:
>
> The dog must be accompanied by a certificate signed by a full-time
>   salaried veterinary official of the region of origin stating that the
>   dog has been inspected for screwworm within 5 days prior to shipment
>   to the United States.
>
> The certificate must state that the dog is either free from screwworm
>   or was found to be infested with screwworm and was held in quarantine
>   and treated until free from screwworm prior to leaving the region.
>
> **Other General Information for Pets**
>
> For an overview of the process of traveling with your pet, watch this
>   short video.
>
> In order to expedite entry into the United States, we suggest that you
>   do not use straw, hay, grass, or other natural bedding. Our Plant
>   Protection and Quarantine Division does not allow the importation of
>   these materials as they may harbor various plant pests.
>
> We also suggest you contact your State, county, municipal authorities
>   for local restrictions on importing dogs. Some airlines require health
>   certificates for dogs traveling with them. You should contact the
>   airlines prior to your travel date.
>
> Pet owners importing cats and dogs into Hawaii can follow the State’s
>   5-Day-or-Less Quarantine Program protocol, which includes a 120-day
>   waiting period prior to arrival in Hawaii and a provision for cats and
>   dogs to be directly released to their owners at Honolulu International
>   Airport after inspection.  Cats and dogs that don’t meet all of the
>   5-Day-or-Less program requirements will be quarantined for up to 120
>   days upon arrival in Hawaii. For more information, please visit the
>   website for the Hawaii Dept. of Agriculture at:
>   http://hdoa.hawaii.gov/ai/aqs/animal-quarantine-information-page/.
>
> All cats and dogs are subject to inspection at ports of entry for
>   evidence of infectious diseases that can be transmitted to humans.
>
> As a help to both domestic and international travelers, The American
>   Society for the Prevention of Cruelty to Animals  web site has a
>   wealth of pertinent information.
>
> Owners of dogs imported from countries or regions affected with
>   Foot-and-Mouth Disease (FMD) are advised to take the following
>   precautions to prevent the introduction of FMD from pets entering the
>   United States:
>
> The feet, fur, and bedding of the pets should be free of any excessive
>   dirt or mud.
>
> - The pet's bedding should be free of any straw or hay, or other natural bedding.
> - The pet should be bathed as soon as it reaches its final destination.
> - The pet should be kept separate and apart from all livestock for at least 5 days after entry into the United States.